# How to add to an array in javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays

is anyone able to tell me what i am doing wrong? The problem is that "ramdom1" is not being added to the array.(nothing is showing up in the text_loot)

Any help would  be great, thanks.

```
var lootArray = [].join("<br>");

lootArray.add("ramdom1");

document.getElementById("text_loot").innerHTML = lootArray;
```

Comment: I think google is also available for this question .. try googling first before asking here :)

Answer (score 3):

First, the method to add element to array is called `push`, not `add`

Second, when you do `join` on array, you get string, which doesn't have methods like `push` or `add`

If you really want to do this, you need this code:

```
var lootArray = []

lootArray.push("ramdom1");

lootArray = lootArray.join("<br>");

document.getElementById("text_loot").innerHTML = lootArray;
```

Comment: could you recommend a different method? "if you really want to do this"

Answer (score 2):

Replace

```
lootArray.add("ramdom1");
```

with

```
lootArray.push("ramdom1");
```

Answer (score 0):

use push method like this. hope it will works

```
lootArray.push("ramdom1");
```

Comment: oh sorry made it right thanx for correction :)